# core file in /home generated by Xwayland

Tags: kernel, 18.04, wayland

So I started cleaning up my /home folder and ran into a 110MB file named `core`:

```
file core
core: ELF 64-bit LSB core file x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), SVR4-style, from '/usr/bin/Xwayland :0 -rootless -terminate -accessx -core -listen 4 -listen 5 -d', real uid: 1000, effective uid: 1000, real gid: 1000, effective gid: 1000, execfn: '/usr/bin/Xwayland', platform: 'x86_64'
```

From what I understand from reading a bit, core dump files are supposed to indicate the state of the system at the time of an application failure, for the sake of figuring out what went wrong.

My question is, is it common for Xwayland to generate such core files or should I be worried that this is pointing to a serious issue with my 18.04 installation (updated from 17.10, if it matters)? And, as a user who is not familiar with core dump files, is there any simple way to figure out what exactly went wrong in case it's not a minor issue?

Comment: If `gdb` is installed, then `gdb -c core` may give you a little more information about the type of error - but you likely won't get a comprehensive stack trace since the executable won't contain debugging symbols.

Comment: All I get is `Core was generated by  /usr/bin/Xwayland :0 -rootless -terminate -accessx -core -listen 4 -listen 5 -d'.
Program terminated with signal SIGABRT, Aborted.`